# How to Handle Validate two CA Values and Validating the .exe file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to validate these two custom attributes using any iteration method.

```
:: Validate Custom Attribute
set HPSUT_CA=""@HPSUT_Windows@
set SUT_CA=""@SUT_Windows@
```

if any CA Value is Empty  it should exit the code, If any CA value contains it should goto :START_INSTALL

```
:START_INSTALL
:: windows map network drive
set HPSUTx64=Z:\Media\HPSUT\@HPSUT_Windows@
set SUTx64=Z:\Media\SUT\@SUT_Windows@
```

and then it should check for

```
:: Check for Media Server
if exist %HPSUTx64% (
    echo HPSUT %HPSUTx64% exists in Media Server.
    goto :INSTALLHPSUT
) else if exist %SUTx64%(
    echo SUT %SUTx64% exists in Media Server.
    goto :INSTALLSUT
) else (
    echo SUT SUTx64 not found. Please Check for SUT files in Media Server. 
                exit 1
)
```

Help on this how to Handle this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:: Check for Media Server
if exist %HPSUTx64% (
    echo HPSUT %HPSUTx64% exists in Media Server.
    goto :INSTALLHPSUT
) else if exist %SUTx64%(
    echo SUT %SUTx64% exists in Media Server.
    goto :INSTALLSUT
) else (
    echo SUT SUTx64 not found. Please Check for SUT files in Media Server. 
                exit 1
)